# How to achieve offcanvas menu with angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

I'm trying to implement offcanvas menu inside my angular app.
I use angular 1.2. The animation work smoothly but there is one little détail (ans you know, devil lies in the details)
During the animation, an horizontal scrollbar appears. The simple trick that come to my mind was to add a class to the parent div with a

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Only during the animation but I can't figure out how to make this. Any idea?

Comment: Old question, and this is not an answer, but you might find clues at https://github.com/cironunes/angular-off-canvas.  The demo there doesn't display any scrollbars…

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap offcanvas example http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/ uses exactly that trick, but just on the x axis:

```
html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I know, the problem was more on how avoiding overflow:hidden as a general rules. I'm looking for adding it sparingly, only during the animation